# How to write a sql query to select multiple rows of single table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table named `Employee` with fields ID,Key,Value. The table is as below...

```
ID | Key   | Value
1  | Fname | a
1  | Lname | aa
2  | Fname | b
2  | Lname | bb
```

I want the output as below...

```
1  | a | aa 
2  | b | bb
```

Please tell me the query to produce such output...

Comment: try something first; question is too broad

Comment: btw, `key` is a MySQL reserved word; thought you'd like to know that beforehand https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- yet another pivot table question, linked the appropriate duplicate for it

Comment: @Shadow Gosh darn it, I voted too soon. Oh well, it'll be picked up eventually. Thanks for finding that. Edit: Ah, it did get picked up.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorted now. DV and delete

Comment: @RiggsFolly I wouldn't go as far as deleting. OP's pretty new to this and thought the answer was good. But one down below should though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yet another pivot table question and the same answer given again as in the dozens of other pivot table questions do not add any value to SO, therefore I also support deletion. I see at least 1 MySQL pivot table question per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use case and aggregate to achieve that:

```
select `ID`, 
  max(case when `Key` = 'Fname' then `Value` end) fname,
  max(case when `Key` = 'Lname' then `Value` end) lname
from Employee
group by `ID`;
```

P.S. - Avoid using (MySQL) reserved keywords such as `key` etc. in your design.

Reference:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: Thanks I just changed the column named key and the query worked fine.. Thanks guyz for helping...

Answer (score -3):

If you want to select all multiple rows then

```
SELECT*FROM ROW_NAME;
```

And if you want to select particularly then

```
SELECT NAME,NAME,NAME,FROM ROW_NAME
```

here NAME is for select you want.

Comment: That isn't what the question is about.

Comment: Also, in the real world, you should almost never use `Select *`, unless you're actually using ALL of the rows in the table, as this is a performance hit pulling in data that you're not making use of.